# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException when request rest json service with jersey client

Tags: json, rest, jersey

I have a rest webservice (with jersey) which returns json list, if i call it directly it returns exactly this :

```
[{"success":false,"uri":"foo:22","message":"Unknown host : foo"},{"success":true,"uri":"localhost:8082","message":null}]
```

generated by this snippet :

```
@GET
@Path("/opening/")
public List<OpeningResult> testOpenings(@QueryParam("uri") List<String> uris) {
    LOG.debug("testOpenings request uris :[" + uris + "]");
    List<OpeningResult> openingResults = infoService.testOpenings(uris);
    return openingResults;
}
```

It's a Collection of Pojo which look like this :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "OpeningResult")
public class OpeningResult {

attributes
...
getter/setter

}
```

this Pojo is shared through a common jar between the server and the client.

i call the web service with this snippet :

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource resource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/scheduler/rest/opening");
MultivaluedMap<String, String> params = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
for (String uri : uris) {
    params.add("uri", uri);
}
List<OpeningResult> results = newArrayList(resource.queryParams(params).get(OpeningResult[].class));
```

I add some trace on the server side, i see that my rest service is called with the good parameters, buth on client side, i have this error :

```
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"success"). Expected elements are <{}OpeningResult>
```

I don't find where it comes from ?

Comment: Can you post the server side code that publishes your Pojo?

Comment: i edited my message with the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code to set up your client like this:

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, true);
Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
```

I had the exact same problem until [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9627170/356408) pointed me in the right direction.

The situation is caused by the default [jersey-json module](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/JSONConfiguration-FEATURE-POJO-MAPPING-td6020373.html) used for serialization to and from JSON, which does not handle certain JSON constructs properly.

You can set the [`FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING`](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html#json.pojo.approach.section) flag to use the Jackson library's JacksonJsonProvider for JSON serialization instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Jersey Client side doc on using JSON](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html). It looks like you're at least missing the annotation:

```
@Produces("application/json")
```

But you could also be missing the POJO Mapping feature filters for both client and server side. These all seem to be minor configuration changes.

Comment: Nop i already put this annotation on the class, not on each method. And the pojo is well annotated.

Comment: The POJO Mapping features are not specific to your class. They are filters you configure for the Web Application and the ClientConfig class. This is what I meant by "feature filters for both client and server side."
http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html#json.jaxb.approach.section